# Does a straightforward algorithm refer to the algorithm which intuitively solves a specific problem?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to figure out what is a straightforward algorithm.

The following pseudocode comes from section 4.2 of "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein"

[image]

Is it a straightforward algorithm?

Does a straightforward algorithm refer to the algorithm which intuitively solves a specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a straightforward algorithm.

There is no special mathematical or computational meaning that is attached to the word "straightforward" here. It just means what it means in plain English, as by [Google search by me today](https://www.google.com/search?q=straightforward+dictionary),

> uncomplicated and easy to do or understand.

---

To be slightly pedantic, I would avoid saying "a straightforward algorithm refers to the algorithm which **intuitively** solves a specific problem". Usually, we use intuition when we rely on some instinct, heuristics or experience . The algorithm here, which computes the square of a matrix, is implemented strictly according to the definition of matrix multiplication. This implementation is completely mechanical, assuming the ability to transform a specification of a procedure into program.

"Straightforward" is, indeed, the most appropriate word to describe the algorithm.